# LaunchScreen storyboard is it mandatory for App Store app

Tags: swift, xcode

I coded my app with several ViewControllers including an initial WelcomeVC. My app works well and I have no delay when launching it. I have seen that LaunchScreen.storyboard is used for first screen when app is launched but I don't need it in my app. I want to use it and submit it this way to the App Store without LaunchScreen. Do you know if this is possible?
Nevertheless I tried to add a simple LaunchScreen but I see no utility as on my Iphone when the App starts it goes so quick that I don't see the LaunchScreen.
Can I post an app without LaunchScreen?

Answer (score 0):

> Can I post an app without LaunchScreen?

No. Well, you can post it, but it will be rejected.

The launch screen does more than just provide an interim screen during launch. It also acts as a signal so that the device knows your app can adapt to it. Therefore Apple now requires (or soon will require) that an app submitted to the app store have a launch screen.

Comment: Thanks for your response, it's now clear for me that the LaunchScreen is mandatory. Still not very clear why it is needed as I like to understand what is behind the process. As said my app is working with a LaunchScreen but I kept it blank and everything works fine. Do you know if the review team will accept such "blank" format?